# How to filter in django with empty fields when using ChoiceField

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-filter

I have a programme where users should be able to filter different types of technologies by their attributes. My question is, how would I filter the technologies when there's potential conflicts and empty values in the parameters I use to filter?

Forms.py:

```
class FilterDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ASSESSMENT = (('', ''),('Yes', 'Yes'),('No', 'No'),)

    q01_suitability_for_task_x = forms.ChoiceField(label='Is the technology suitable for x?',
    choices=ASSESSMENT, help_text='Please select yes or no', required=False,)
    q02_suitability_for_environment_y = forms.ChoiceField(label='Is the technology suitable for environment Y?',
    choices=ASSESSMENT, help_text='Please select yes or no', required=False)
```

There are many fields in my model like the ones above.

views.py

```
class TechListView(ListView):
    model = MiningTech
def get_queryset(self):
        q1 = self.request.GET.get('q01_suitability_for_task_x', '')
        q2 = self.request.GET.get('q02_suitability_for_environment_y', '')

object_list = MiningTech.objects.filter(q01_suitability_for_task_x=q1).filter(
        q02_suitability_for_environment_y=q2)

return object_list
```

The difficulty is that not all technology db entries will have data. So in my current setup there's times where I will filter out objects that have one attribute but not another.

For instance if my db has:
pk1: q01_suitability_for_task_x=Yes; q02_suitability_for_environment_y=Yes;
pk2: q01_suitability_for_task_x=Yes; q02_suitability_for_environment_y='';

In the form, if I don't select any value for q01_suitability_for_task_x, and select Yes for q02_suitability_for_environment_y, I get nothing back in the queryset because there are no q01_suitability_for_task_x empty fields.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm also ok with restructuring everything if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `self.request.GET.get(...)` code defaults to an empty string if there is no value found, so your model `.filter()` is looking for matches where the string is `''`.

I would restructure the first part of `get_queryset()` to build a dictionary that can be unpacked into your filter. If the value doesn't exist then it doesn't get added to the filter dictionary:

```py
filters = {}
q1 = self.request.GET.get('q01_suitability_for_task_x', None)
q2 = self.request.GET.get('q02_suitability_for_environment_y', None)

if q1 is not None:
   filters['q01_suitability_for_task_x'] = q1

... etc ...

object_list = MiningTech.objects.filter(**filters)
```

If you have a lot of q1, q2, etc. items then consider putting them in a list, looping through and inserting into the dictionary if `.get(...)` returns anything.

Edit: Because there are indeed a lot possible filters, the final solution looks as follows:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    filters = {}
    for key, value in self.request.GET.items():
        if value != '':
            filters[key] = value

    object_list =  Tech.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'm editing the answer with my final solution so I can accept it